# Error using sails.js and postgreSQL (using sails-postgresql module)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I want to ask a question. I'm developing an app using sails.js and PostgreSQL (using sails-postgresql module). I'm using UUID for my primary key type instead of integer. But there are some error when I try to insert a data to my database.

my model `UserModel.js`

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid'); 

module.exports = {

    adapter: 'somePostgresqlServer',
    autoPK: false,
    migrate: 'safe',
    attributes: {
        ID: {
            primaryKey: true,
            type: 'string',
            defaultsTo: function (){
                return uuid.v4(); 
            },
            unique: true,
            index: true,
            uuidv4: true
        },

        username: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            unique: true
        }   
    }
};
```

my create function in the controller

```
create: function(req, res) {
        if (!req.param('_username') || !req.param('_newPassword') ||
            !req.param('_confirmPassword') || !req.param('_emailAddress') ||
            !req.param('_firstName') || !req.param('_lastName')) {
            var errorMessage = ["All field are required to sign up"];
            req.session.flash = {
                err : errorMessage
            }
            res.redirect('/login');
            return;
        }

        if (req.param('_newPassword') != req.param('_confirmPassword')) {
            var errorMessage = ["New password and confirm password must be same"];
            req.session.flash = {
                err : errorMessage
            }
            res.redirect('/login');
            return; 
        }

        UserModel.create({
            username: req.param('_username'),
            encryptedPassword: req.param('_newPassword'),
            emailAddress: req.param('_emailAddress'),
            firstName: req.param('_firstName'),
            lastName: req.param('_lastName')
        }).exec(function(err,post) {
            if (err) {
                return res.error();
            }

            res.redirect('/');
        })

        res.redirect('/');
    }
```

the error

```
/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:393
        Object.keys(collection.schema).forEach(function(schemaKey) {
               ^
TypeError: Object.keys called on non-object
    at Function.keys (native)
    at __CREATE__ (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:393:16)
    at after (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:1155:7)
    at /home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:1049:7
    at /home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:77:9
    at dispense (/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:250:16)
    at Object.me.acquire (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:319:5)
    at Object.pool.connect (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:71:12)
    at PG.connect (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/node_modules/pg/lib/index.js:49:8)
    at spawnConnection (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:1048:8)
    at Object.module.exports.adapter.create (/home/***/***/***/node_modules/sails-postgresql/lib/adapter.js:361:7)
    at module.exports.create (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/adapter/dql.js:84:13)
    at bound.createValues (/usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:214:16)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/dql/create.js:74:20
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:708:13
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:49:16
```

I wish you can help me. Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

#### Model

```
    var uuid = require('node-uuid'); 

    module.exports = {

        adapter: 'somePostgresqlServer',
        autoPK: false,
        attributes: {
            id: {
                primaryKey : true,
                type       : 'string',
                defaultsTo : function (){
                    return uuid.v4(); 
                },
                unique     : true,
                index      : true
            },

            username: {
                type     : 'string',
                required : true,
                unique   : true
            }
        }
    };
```

#### Controller

```
    create: function(req, res) {
        var username        = req.param('_username'),
            newPassword     = req.param('_newPassword'),
            confirmPassword = req.param('_confirmPassword'),
            emailAddress    = req.param('_emailAddress'),
            firstName       = req.param('_firstName'),
            lastName        = req.param('_lastName');

        if (!(username || newPassword || confirmPassword || emailAddress || firstName || lastName)) {
            var errorMessage = ["All field are required to sign up"];
            req.session.flash = {
                err : errorMessage
            }
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }

        if (newPassword != confirmPassword) {
            var errorMessage = ["New password and confirm password must be same"];
            req.session.flash = {
                err : errorMessage
            }
            return res.redirect('/login');
        }

        UserModel
          .create({
            username          : username,
            encryptedPassword : newPassword,
            emailAddress      : emailAddress,
            firstName         : firstName,
            lastName          : lastName
          })
          .then(function(post) {
            res.redirect('/');
          })
          .catch(res.negotiate);
    }
```

1. At models definition, there are no exist `migrate`, it's on model configuration.
2. `uuidv4` also not a valid attribute.
3. `id` field is necessary while you use `Blueprint API`, look after blueprint hooks at `actionUtil` in your sails at `node_modules`.
4. Don't call `res.redirect` at the end of controller while you have async. process, it will give race condition when query not completed yet and you will get redirected.

Actually I don't pretty sure if it will solve your problem, but you can try it and give a result later.